# SQL Server 2008 R2 - user disk quota

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to apply restrictions on how much data a user / login may store in a database? I found no way to apply such restrictions to schemas, for instance.

If there is no built-in mechanism then I'm curious if someone had implemented some kind of it.

Seems a bit ridiculous, I know but we have some users and want them to restrict writing too much data into `WorkDB` so that their activities (queries, inserts) wouldn't eat out all the resources.

Resource Governor can only maintain CPU/RAM.

Environment: SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise edition.

Answer (score 1):

There is one option as I know: one user - one database. Set **Initial Size** and disable **Autogrowth** (database options).

Comment: Yes, this is first that comes up. Anyway, thanks for that =)

Answer (score 1):

No. You can howver restrict the DB size (garik already pointed out that) but also you can restrict individual files and thus restrict filegroups, and you can assign specific user tables to specific filegroups. Is a workaround, but it can work. See Files and [Filegroups Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179316.aspx)